# how do i update table row content while also reordering the table row

Tags: jquery

How can i refresh the all table row or the entire table , and on each refresh i have to reorder the table row content to search for td class = points, and have the table rows displayed from highest to lowest sum depending on value of td.points ?

I'm so confused on what to do here. New to using jQuery and really out of my element , so appreciate it.

```
<table class="homepagemodule report" id="livescoring_summary" align="center" cellspacing="1">
   <caption><span>Live Scoring</span></caption>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th colspan="3"><a>Week 1</a></th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td>Gridiron Grunts</td>
         <td class="points" id="fid_00011">87.03</td>
         <td><a>Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow">
         <td>LDSDEMOTEAM</td>
         <td class="points" id="fid_00021">58.10</td>
         <td><a>Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="oddtablerow">
         <td>Franchise 3</td>
         <td class="points" id="fid_00031">74.050</td>
         <td><a>Details</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="eventablerow">
         <td>LDSDEMOTEAM</td>
         <td class="points" id="fid_00021">123.02</td>
         <td><a>Details</a></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: on what event you want to accomplish that? do you have any js so far?

Comment: No event , I just want it to auto update every 5 minutes

Comment: You need to at least make an attempt.  People aren't going to spoon feed you on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I've made attempts but it's probably laughable so I didn't post

Comment: I made a script, which re-arange the order of `tr`'s based on the `td.points`. take a look, if it is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


  function arrangeRows(){


var tableBody=$("#livescoring_summary").find('tbody');

var tableRows=$("#livescoring_summary").find('tr').not(':first-child'); 

var res=[];

tableRows.each(function(){ 
  res.push($(this));

});  

res.sort(function(row1, row2) {
 return parseInt(row1.find('.points').html()) -   parseInt(row2.find('.points').html());
});

for(i=res.length-1; i>=0; i--){  

  $(res[i]).appendTo(tableBody);    

}


  }


  setInterval(arrangeRows,1000);



});
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbt5k7yd/)

Test it with multiple values.

Change the second argument in `setInterval(arrangeRows,1000);` to any number of ms you want this function tu be called. 5minutes (300*1000) ms